# how to redirect different types of pages to different users after login in django

Tags: django, django-registration, django-login, django-custom-user

I have created two different types of users - truck & company using Django. Here is my registration page of a user [Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wGJR.png)

After registering, the data about whether the user is a truck or company will go to the database.

In my login page, only EmailID and Password are to be entered.

I would like to know how a user with a unique EmailID can redirects to a valid page based on the type of user.

Comment: Any code piece you have tried

Comment: Nope, I haven't tried anything. I am new to Django. I just created the registration page and login page and stuck after that. No idea moving further. Can i share the details of my CustomUser creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need something like that;

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean()
            login(request, form.user_cache)
            if form.user_cache.type == 'truck':
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/where')
            elif form.user_cache.type == 'company':
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/where/else')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I haven't created an AuthenticationForm in my forms.py. I just created a CustomRegistrationForm so that the user details can save into somewhere else. But I am able to get the user details to my views.py. May i know how can i do that.

Comment: Actually AuthenticationForm is from ```from django.contrib.auth.forms```. I didn't need a complex authentication so i took the one of Django.

Answer (score 0):

Your customized user model is probably something like this:

```
class myuser(models.Model):
    myUser = models.ForeignKey(User,..)
    userType = models.CharField(choices=(('truck','truck'),('company','company'))
```

Your view should be something like this:

```
def login(request):
# authentication and getting the data from POST request to your login page,
# i assume you have a variable called user and you have your user object in it
    userType = user.userType
    if userType == company:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/url/')
    if userType == truck:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/other/url/')
```